# Unique validation on update Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a Laravel application. I am performing the user information update function, but I can't bypass the validation check for the admin_email and admin_title fields in the tbl_admin database. I am using the following FormRequest:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests;
use App\Models\Admin;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
class UserRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    
    public function rules()
    {
        $admin_id = $this->route('admin.edit');
        return [
            'account_title_name' => ['required', 'email', Rule::unique('tbl_admin', 'admin_email')->ignore($admin_id)],
            'account_titleshow_name' => 'required|max:40', 
            'account_password_name' => 'required|min:8|regex:/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()]).*$/',
            'account_tell_name' => 'required|regex:/(0)[0-9]/|not_regex:/[a-z]/|min:10|max:10|unique:tbl_admin,admin_phone',
            'account_roles_name' => 'required',    
        ];
    }
    
    
    public function messages(){
        return [
            'account_title_name.required'=>':attribute là bắt buộc', 
            'account_title_name.email'=>':attribute không đúng định dạng email (Chứa @gmail.com)',
            'account_title_name.max'=>':attribute vượt quá quy định :max',
            'account_title_name.max'=>':attribute vượt quá quy định :max',
            'account_title_name.unique'=>':attribute đã tồn tại', 
            'account_titleshow_name.required'=>':attribute là bắt buộc', 
            'account_titleshow_name.max'=>':attribute vượt quá quy định :max', 
            'account_password_name.required'     =>  ':attribute là bắt buộc', 
            'account_password_name.min'     =>  ':attribute có ít nhất :min ký tự', 
            'account_password_name.regex'     =>  ':attribute phải chứa ký tự viết hoa và kí tự đặc biệt', 
            'account_tell_name.required'=>':attribute là bắt buộc', 
            'account_tell_name.min'=>':attribute phải đủ :min số',
            'account_tell_name.max'=>':attribute vượt quá quy định :max số',
            'account_tell_name.regex'=>':attribute không đúng định dạng', 
            'account_tell_name.not_regex'=>':attribute không đúng định dạng',
            'account_tell_name.unique'=>':attribute đã tồn tại',
            'account_roles_name.required'     =>  ':attribute',     
        ];
    }
    public function attributes(){
        return [
            'account_title_name'=>'Tên tài khoản',
            'account_titleshow_name'=>'Tên hiển thị', 
            'account_password_name'=>'Mật khẩu',
            'account_roles_name'     =>  'Chọn một quyền cho tài khoản', 
            'account_tell_name'     =>  'Số điện thoại',  
        ];
    }
    protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
       if($this->wantsJson())
       {
           $response = response()->json([
               'status' => 0,
               'error'=>$validator->errors()->toArray()//$validator->errors()
               
           ]);
       }else{
           $response = redirect()
               //->route('guest.login')
               ->with('message', 'Ops! Some errors occurred')
               ->withErrors($validator);
       } 
       throw (new ValidationException($validator, $response))
           ->errorBag($this->errorBag)
           ->redirectTo($this->getRedirectUrl());
   }


}
```

I hope someone will help me fix this issue so that I can update the user information and save the data. Here is the code of my FormRequest.
**1. Controller**

```
public function Edit_user($admin_id)
      {   
        $this->AuthLogin ();
        $admin = Auth::user();
        // Kiểm tra người dùng có phải là admin hay không
        if($admin->admin_id) {
        $edit_field = Admin::where('admin_id', $admin_id)->first(); 
        $roles_show = AdminRole::where('admin_admin_id', $admin_id)->first(); 
        } 
          return view('admin.users.form.edit_users', compact('roles_show','edit_field')); 
      }
      public function Update_user(UserRequest $request, $admin_id)
      {   

          $form_update = [
              'admin_email' => $request->input('account_title_name'),
              'admin_password' => md5($request->input('account_password_name')),
              'admin_name' => $request->input('account_titleshow_name'),
              'admin_phone' => $request->input('account_tell_name'),
             //'admin_id' => $request->input('admin_id_name'),
          ];
          $admin = Admin::whereid($admin_id )->update($form_update);
          AdminRole::updateOrCreate(
              ['admin_admin_id' => $admin->admin_id],
              ['roles_id_roles' => $request->input('account_roles_name')]
          );
          Toastr::success('Cập nhật thành công', 'Thành công'); 
          return response()->json(['status'=>1, 'msg'=>'Cập nhật thông tin người dùng thành công']);
      }
```

**2. Models Admin (Database tbl_admin)**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'admin_id','admin_email', 'admin_password', 'admin_name','admin_phone'
    ];
    protected $primaryKey = 'admin_id';
    protected $table = 'tbl_admin';
    
    public function roles(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Roles');
    }
    
    public function getAuthPassword(){
        return $this->admin_password;
    }
        public function hasAnyRoles($roles){

        if(is_array($roles)){
            foreach($roles as $role){
                if($this->hasRole($role)){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }else{
            if($this->hasRole($roles)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public function hasRole($role){
        if($this->roles()->where('name',$role)->first()){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**3. Routes**

```
route::get('/edit-user/{admin_id}','App\Http\Controllers\UserController@Edit_user')->name('admin.edit');
route::post('/update-user/{admin_id}','App\Http\Controllers\UserController@Update_user');``
```

Comment: High speed hashes like MD5 and SHA1 are considered broken for security purposes and are not sufficient for password hashing. Instead use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

Comment: hat do you mean by " I can't bypass the validation check for the admin_email and admin_title fields in the tbl_admin database" ? did you check if `$admin_id = $this->route('admin.edit');` has the right value ? did you try `$admin_id = $this->admin_id;` instead ?

Answer (score 0):

you can access the parameters in the Update_User function by using the $this keyword.

then the rule() function is like this:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'account_title_name' => "required|email|unique:tbl_admin,admin_email,{$this->admin_id}",
        'account_titleshow_name' => 'required|max:40', 
        'account_password_name' => 'required|min:8|regex:/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()]).*$/',
        'account_tell_name' => 'required|regex:/(0)[0-9]/|not_regex:/[a-z]/|min:10|max:10|unique:tbl_admin,admin_phone',
        'account_roles_name' => 'required',    
    ];
}
```

$this keyword also applies to fetch other fields, like `$this->account_title_name`, `$this->account_titleshow_name`.

.....

if you get error then you have to tell what the primary_key column.

then it can be solved like this:

```
'account_title_name' => "required|email|unique:tbl_admin,admin_email,{$this->admin_id},admin_id",
```

let me give details: `unique:table_name,column_name,except_based_id,primary_key`

Comment: hi you! I tried to use this method, but my application still doesn't work. The Laravel log file reports the following error: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `tbl_admin` where `admin_email` = bao121@gmail.com and `id` <> 63) {"userId":2,"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 42S22): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `tbl_admin` where `admin_email` = bao121@gmail.com and `id` <> 63)

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions as directed, but still failed and Laravel log reported an error (Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'tbl_admin'). Currently, I am using 'admin_id' as the primary key in the 'tbl_admin' table. I would appreciate any help with this issue.

Comment: if you get this error then you have to tell what the primary_key column is.

then it can be solved like this: `'account_title_name' => "required|email|unique:tbl_admin,admin_email,{$this->admin_id},admin_id",`.

let me give details: `unique:table_name,column_name,except_based_id,primary_key`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

**My issue has not been resolved and this error appears in the Laravel log file**

[previous exception] [object] (PDOException(code: 42S22): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' at C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:368)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(368): PDO->prepare('select count(*)...')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(705): Illuminate\Database\Connection->Illuminate\Database\{closure}('select count(*)...', Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(672): Illuminate\Database\Connection->runQueryCallback('select count(*)...', Array, Object(Closure))
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(376): Illuminate\Database\Connection->run('select count(*)...', Array, Object(Closure))
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php(2414): Illuminate\Database\Connection->select('select count(*)...', Array, false)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php(2402): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->runSelect()
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php(2936): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->Illuminate\Database\Query\{closure}()
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php(2403): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->onceWithColumns(Array, Object(Closure))
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php(2863): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->get(Array)
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php(2791): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->aggregate('count', Array)
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Validation\DatabasePresenceVerifier.php(55): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->count()
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Validation\Concerns\ValidatesAttributes.php(856): Illuminate\Validation\DatabasePresenceVerifier->getCount('tbl_admin', 'admin_email', 'bao123@gmail.co...', '59', 'id', Array)
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Validation\Validator.php(610): Illuminate\Validation\Validator->validateUnique('account_title_n...', 'bao123@gmail.co...', Array, Object(Illuminate\Validation\Validator))
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Validation\Validator.php(416): Illuminate\Validation\Validator->validateAttribute('account_title_n...', 'Unique')
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Validation\Validator.php(447): Illuminate\Validation\Validator->passes()
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Validation\ValidatesWhenResolvedTrait.php(25): Illuminate\Validation\Validator->fails()
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FormRequestServiceProvider.php(30): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest->validateResolved()
#17 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(1265): Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FormRequestServiceProvider->Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\{closure}(Object(App\Http\Requests\UserRequest), Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
#18 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(1230): Illuminate\Container\Container->fireCallbackArray(Object(App\Http\Requests\UserRequest), Array)
#19 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(1215): Illuminate\Container\Container->fireAfterResolvingCallbacks('App\\Http\\Reques...', Object(App\Http\Requests\UserRequest))
#20 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(778): Illuminate\Container\Container->fireResolvingCallbacks('App\\Http\\Reques...', Object(App\Http\Requests\UserRequest))
#21 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(851): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('App\\Http\\Reques...', Array, true)
#22 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(694): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve('App\\Http\\Reques...', Array)
#23 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(836): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('App\\Http\\Reques...', Array)
#24 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php(79): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('App\\Http\\Reques...')
#25 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php(48): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->transformDependency(Object(ReflectionParameter), Array, Object(stdClass))
#26 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php(28): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->resolveMethodDependencies(Array, Object(ReflectionMethod))
#27 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php(41): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->resolveClassMethodDependencies(Array, Object(App\Http\Controllers\UserController), 'Update_user')
#28 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php(262): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(App\Http\Controllers\UserController), 'Update_user')
#29 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php(205): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController()
#30 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(721): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run()
#31 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#32 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\app\Http\Middleware\AccessAdmin.php(23): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#33 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): App\Http\Middleware\AccessAdmin->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#34 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings.php(50): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#35 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#36 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php(78): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#37 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#38 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#39 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#40 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession.php(121): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#41 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handleStatefulRequest(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Illuminate\Session\Store), Object(Closure))
#42 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#43 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#44 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#45 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies.php(67): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#46 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#47 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#48 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(723): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#49 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(698): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#50 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(662): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route))
#51 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(651): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#52 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(167): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#53 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#54 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#55 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#56 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#57 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#58 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#59 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#60 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#61 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#62 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#63 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#64 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\fruitcake\laravel-cors\src\HandleCors.php(38): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#65 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#66 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies.php(39): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#67 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#68 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#69 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(142): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#70 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(111): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#71 C:\xampp\htdocs\bao-hanh-demo\index.php(52): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#72 {main}
"}

Comment: Please comment on the solutions you have tried, or better yet, expand your question with the information you get from testing. Do not create answers to your question that only contain more error messages.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I tried the methods you suggested, but the result was the same error as follows: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `tbl_admin` where `admin_email` = bao121@gmail.com and `id` <> 63) {"userId":2,"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 42S22): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `tbl_admin` where `admin_email` = bao121@gmail.com and `id` <> 63) at 2)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).